# Foreach dentro de Foreach PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$row = $twitterusers->selectUserAll();

foreach ($row as $fetch) {
    $users[] = $fetch;
}

var_dump($users);
```

Ele pega todos os usuários da tabela, porém ao usar o `var_dump` percebo que tem `array` dentro de `array`, veja:

```
0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user_id' => string '123' (length=18)
      'screen_name' => string 'login1' (length=13)
      'oauth_token' => string 'token-hash' (length=50)
      'oauth_token_secret' => string 'token-hash2' (length=45)
      'vip' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'user_id' => string '1234' (length=18)
      'screen_name' => string 'login2' (length=12)
      'oauth_token' => string 'token-hash' (length=50)
      'oauth_token_secret' => string 'token-hash2' (length=45)
      'vip' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Eu queria pegar todos os `users_id`, mas não estou conseguindo, exemplo:

Ao invés de `0 =>` e `1 =>`, gostaria que ficasse tudo em um array só, como posso fazer isso?

Obs: imprimir todos os ids da seguinte forma:

```
user_id => 123
user_id => 1234
user_id => 1235
user_id => 1236
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$fetch = $twitterusers->selectUserAll();

foreach ($fetch as $row) {
    $usersIds[] = $row['id'];
}

var_dump($usersIds);
```

Ou melhor ainda, sem precisar iterar com [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php):

```
$fetch = $twitterusers->selectUserAll();

$userIds = array_column($fetch, 'id');

var_dump($usersIds);
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou, e olha que eu fiz deste jeito o porque de não funcionar eu não sei. Vou esperar dar o tempo que ta pedindo pra marcar como resolvido, vlw obrigado gmsantos.

Comment: até funcionou, mas queria juntar esses id's tudo em um array só exemplo: 0 => id1, id,2 id,3 teria como ?

Comment: Mas é isso q ele é hj, cada key desse array é um id que você itera e vê o resultado de cada. Ele não é um array multidimensional, como vc está querendo.

Comment: entendo, é que ele não está funcionando todos id's, apenas 3 funciona. mas tentarei concertar.