# Arrays em um único índice

Tags: php, array, foreach

Fiz esta [pergunta hoje](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223854/foreach-dentro-de-foreach-php/223858?noredirect=1#comment458304_223858), me ajudou muito, agora tenho o código:

```
foreach ($tokens as $row) {
    $token1[] = $row['oauth_token'];
    $token2[] = $row['oauth_token_secret'];
}

var_dump($token1);
var_dump($token2);
```

E ele me retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria transformar esses tokens tudo em **1** índice só como posso fazer isto?

Exemplo:

```
0 => string 'todos aqui';
```

========================================

## **EDIT:1**

Eu quero extrair os índices, dos arrays por exemplo, tenho agora isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

usando este código:

```
while ($tokens = $this->selectTokens()) {
    foreach ($tokens as $row) {
        $tokenList[] = [
            'oauth_token'               => $row['oauth_token'],
            'oauth_token_secret'    => $row['oauth_token_secret'],
        ];
    }

    #$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $tokenList['oauth_token'], $tokenList['oauth_token_secret']);

    var_dump($tokenList);

    break;
}
```

Bom acho que deu pra entender até aí, agora quero que entendam isto:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $tokenList['oauth_token'], $tokenList['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Ou seja, pegar todos `oauth_token` e `oauth_token_secret`, que vem de um `banco de dados`, para fazer um **looping**. Mas fazendo isso recebo isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Justamente aqui `$tokenList['oauth_token'], $tokenList['oauth_token_secret']`

Comment: Mas todos juntos numa só `string` ? ou uma `string` para os `oauth_token` e outra para o `oauth_token_secret` ?

Comment: Isso, preciso passar no TwitterOAuth veja este print de como ficou agora: http://prntscr.com/g09nwb, o problema é recuperar eles agora. com o código da resposta a baixo, fiz de tudo, mas só me retorna 1, preciso que retorne todos, exemplo tokenList[1] retorna http://prntscr.com/g09ohu, preciso separar isso. por exemplo tokenList['oauth_token'] e tokenList['oauth_token_secret']

Comment: Mas ficaria então para o `oauth_token` com 1 token com o tamanho de 500 caracteres? É essa a ideia?

Comment: A ideia é retornar, todos os tokens tanto token, quanto secret entendeu? em um loop e passar no TwitterOAuth: veja se consegue entender com esste print http://prntscr.com/g09r6p, mas fazendo isso da Undefined index: oauth_token

Comment: **Obs:** esses tokens vem do `Banco de Dados`

Comment: Tanto quanto vi agora na documentação do Twitter essa classe só pode receber 1 oath_token e 1 oath_token_secret. Logo colocar mais numa string provavelmente não iria funcionar, mas posso ter ficado com a ideia errada.

Comment: Isac funciona, eu tenho um código parecido mas usando `mysql_*` com PDO estou tendo problemas.

Comment: Essa instrução tem de tar dentro do `for` no fim dele, e vai criar uma conexão para cada token/`$row`

Comment: tem algum exemplo? sem querer ser ignorante, mas não entendi :(

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com um exemplo do que estava a tentar dizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajustando o código que agora mostrou de conexão a conexão tem de passar para dentro do `for`:

```
while ($tokens = $this->selectTokens()) {
    foreach ($tokens as $row) {
        $tokenList[] = [
            'oauth_token'               => $row['oauth_token'],
            'oauth_token_secret'    => $row['oauth_token_secret'],
        ];

        //uma conexao para cada registo aqui
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $tokenList['oauth_token'], $tokenList['oauth_token_secret']);
    }
}

//agora aqui tem uma lista de conexões estabelecidas em $connection

print_r($connection);
```

Mais simples é utilizar o `$row` diretamente:

```
while ($tokens = $this->selectTokens()) {
    foreach ($tokens as $row) {  
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                         $row['oauth_token'], $row['oauth_token_secret']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim eu tentei isto também, vou editar meu tópico e explicar certo.

Comment: @WillBB Lol bem me parecia que não era o pretendido. Mas infelizmente não consegui perceber qual era o objetivo mesmo. Tente exemplificar um resultado para que fique claro.

Comment: editei o tópico vê se consegue entender agora.

Comment: `Undefined index: oauth_token in C:\wamp64\www\megafollowapi\api\class\TwitterOAuthHelper.php on line 40` bom acho que vc me deu uma luz vou tentar arrumar.

Comment: @WillBB Linha 40 é qual?

Comment: "Mais simples é utilizar o $row diretamente:", agora está me retornando certo cara, obrigado.

Comment: Só uma correção, não utilize `$connection[]` e sim `$connection` se não duplica os tokens. e apenas quero 1 de cada ^_^